# Retrieving geometry in GeoPandas dataframe as json [Edit: use .to_json()]

Tags: geopandas

Having loaded a geojson file into GeoPandas, I get the expected column / feature called "geometry", containing polygons and multipolygons.

How do I get this object out again as a json or Python dict?

In it's current form, it is a `geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries` object.

For example, I need something like:

```
geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -73.76336816099996, 40.726165522000031 ], [ -73.762895342999968, 40.726101379000056 ], [ -73.761940118999973, 40.725972874000036 ], [ -73.76074889399996, 40.725792699000067 ] ] ] ] }
```

Not seeing anything on this in the doc:

http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#overview-of-attributes-and-methods

Comment: Function found: .to_json()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a GeoSeries object (or a GeoDataFrame, the below works the same), such as

```
>>> import geopandas
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point
>>> s = geopandas.GeoSeries([Point(1, 1), Point(2, 2)])
>>> s
0    POINT (1 1)
1    POINT (2 2)
dtype: object
```

then you can convert this to a GeoJSON-like dict with `__geo_interface__`:

```
>>> s.__geo_interface__
{'bbox': (1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0),
 'features': [{'bbox': (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
   'geometry': {'coordinates': (1.0, 1.0), 'type': 'Point'},
   'id': '0',
   'properties': {},
   'type': 'Feature'},
  {'bbox': (2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0),
   'geometry': {'coordinates': (2.0, 2.0), 'type': 'Point'},
   'id': '1',
   'properties': {},
   'type': 'Feature'}],
 'type': 'FeatureCollection'}
```

or to actual GeoJSON (json version of the dict above) with the [`to_json`](http://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_json) method:

```
>>> s.to_json()
'{"type": "FeatureCollection", "bbox": [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0], "features": [{"id": "0", "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"coordinates": [1.0, 1.0], "type": "Point"}, "bbox": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "properties": {}}, {"id": "1", "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"coordinates": [2.0, 2.0], "type": "Point"}, "bbox": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], "properties": {}}]}'
```

In this example it returns a string, but if you pass a file path, it will write that to the file.